# Register callbacks from different classes

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, action, func

For a standard Request Server I use the below code to match a request to a service and process the incoming requests.

**ServiceProvider**

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    public ServiceProvider()
    {
        Services = new Dictionary<Type, IService>
        {
            { typeof(FooRequest), new FooService() },
            { typeof(BarRequest), new BarService() },
        };
    }

    protected void OnRequestReceived(object request)
    {
        Services[request.GetType()].Process(request);
    }
}
```

**FooService**

```
public class FooService : IService
{
    public object Process(object request)
    {
        // Process request
    }
}
```

This works like a charm, but I want to get rid of one method (Process) per service. I tried working with Actions and Delegates but I somehow cannot accomplish this simple structure.

**Basically my question is:** How can I register multiple methods/callbacks from another class and store them in a dictionary for whenever I need to call them?

**Desired result** (pseudocode):

**ServiceProvider**

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    public ServiceProvider()
    {
        var fooService = new FooService();
        var barService = new BarService();

        Handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action>
        {
            { typeof(FooRequestA), fooService.ProcessA },
            { typeof(FooRequestB), fooService.ProcessB },
            { typeof(BarRequest), barService.Process },
        };
    }

    protected void ProcessRequest(object request)
    {
        Handlers[request.GetType()].Invoke(request);
    }
}
```

**FooService**

```
public class FooService
{
    public object ProcessA(FooRequestA request)
    {
        // Process request A
    }

    public object ProcessB(FooRequestB request)
    {
        // Process request B
    }
}
```

**Improvement on solution**

Using the below method you can simplify the recurring request-service matching code:

```
public void RegisterHandler<TRequest>(Action<TRequest> function)
{
    Handlers.Add(typeof(TRequest), request => function.Invoke((TRequest) request));
}
```

Which results in a very clean usage:

```
RegisterHandler<FooRequestA>(request => fooService.ProcessA(request));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with. (while trying to stay close what you asked for... there may be much better ways to achieve what you actually want to do). I think you lose a little type safety with that solution:

**FooService**

```
public class FooService
{
    public object ProcessA(FooRequestA request)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public object ProcessB(FooRequestB request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**BarService**

```
public class BarService
{
    public void Process(BarRequest request)
    { }
}
```

**ServiceProvider**

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> Handlers;
    public ServiceProvider()
    {
        var fooService = new FooService();
        var barService = new BarService();

        Handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
        {
            {typeof(FooRequestA), request => fooService.ProcessA((FooRequestA)request)},
            {typeof(FooRequestB), request => fooService.ProcessB((FooRequestB)request)},
            {typeof(BarRequest), request => barService.Process((BarRequest)request)}
        };
    }

    protected void ProcessRequest(object request)
    {
        Handlers[request.GetType()].Invoke(request);
    }
}
```

Since you cannot convert a method group (like `fooService.ProcessA`) into an `Action`, you need to add lambdas to your `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>` and provide the request as parameter.

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for. Changed it to use Func instead of Action to get a result as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you declare the dictionary as `<Type, Action>`, you cannot pass an argument to `.Invoke(object)` method - `Action` does not accept any arguments. What you probably need is `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>`. I say "probably" because `ProcessA` and `ProcessB`methods return an `object`, so `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>` seems more logical. Anyhow, I hope this is just an educational question because there are other ways far more correct and efficient to accomplish what your'e looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of registering single methods in the `ServiceProvider`, you could also let the services decide which requests they can handle. You could create an interface that contains the following methods (I'm using Request as a base class for all requests to avoid the `object` parameter):

```
public interface IService
{
    bool CanHandle(Request request);
    void Handle(Request request);
}
```

In your registry, you register the services and route the request to the service:

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IService> _registeredServices = new IService[]
        {
             new FooService(), 
             new BarService();
        };

    protected void OnRequestReceived(Request request)
    {
        // Find first service that can handle the request
        var serviceForRequest = 
            _registeredServices.Where(x => x.CanHandle(request)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (serviceForRequest == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No service registered that can handle request " + request.ToString();
        // Let the service handle the request
        serviceForRequest.Handle(request);
    }
}
```

This structure has the advantage that you do not have to change the `ServiceProvider` every time a service can handle a new type of request. Transferred to your sample, you could add the `ProcessB` method to `FooService` and change the implementation of `CanHandle` and `Handle` in the class without having to change the registration.

Instead of registering the services, you can detect them dynamically either by using a IoC container or a reflection-based implementation. In this case you don't have to change the `ServiceProvider` even if you add a new service.

Comment: This is indeed a good alternative. But for my current (simple) setup I find this will lead to less flexible services with just one Process/Handle method. You have to check at service level what kind of request you got and then call an execution path. I want to keep my service classes as clean as possible and let the request decide which execution path to follow without requiring additional Adapter classes.